I am training a siamese network , i have gtx 1650ti but tensorflow is only using CPU. How to utilize GPU
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]

print(get_available_devices())

output: ['/device:CPU:0']

so the gpu is not even showing, is it possible to utilize the GPU ? , if yes please guide me .
i dont think i have installed cudnn or cuda.
I am new tensorflow and ML stuff.
Thank you
I have trained the model without using GPU but it is not giving accurate result.
so i have to retrain with more dataset so i thought use of GPU will make work faster.
regarding GPU utilization i not written any code as GPU was not even showing
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]

print(get_available_devices())

output: ['/device:CPU:0']


To utilize a GPU with TensorFlow, you need to ensure that your system is correctly set up with the necessary GPU libraries and TensorFlow configurations.First, check if your GPU is correctly recognized by your system:nvidia-smiThis command should show details about your GPU, including its utilization and driver version. If it does not show your GPU or reports issues, you might need to update your NVIDIA drivers.
